# I want Cakephp code in my query

Tags: cakephp

I am Cakephp Beginner.
I want this query with cakephp..

Original Query..

```
SELECT `Advertisement`.*, `Gallery`.`image` FROM `moenatmi_moen`.`advertisements`
AS `Advertisement` LEFT JOIN `moenatmi_moen`.`galleries` AS `Gallery` ON 
(`Gallery`.`advertise_id` = `Advertisement`.`id` AND `Gallery`.`main_ad_image`
= 1) WHERE `Advertisement`.`status` = 1 AND `Advertisement`.`category_id` = 14 AND
((`Advertisement`.`expiry_date` >= '2014-11-18') OR (`Advertisement`.`expiry_date`
IS NULL)) GROUP BY `Advertisement`.`id` ORDER BY `Advertisement`.`id` desc
LIMIT 10
```

I Want Like this query..

```
SELECT `Advertisement`.*, `Gallery`.`image` FROM `moenatmi_moen`.`advertisements`
AS `Advertisement` LEFT JOIN `moenatmi_moen`.`galleries` AS `Gallery` ON
(`Gallery`.`advertise_id` = `Advertisement`.`id` AND `Gallery`.`main_ad_image` = 1)
WHERE `Advertisement`.`status` = 1 AND `Advertisement`.`category_id` IN (select id from
categories where id=14 or parent_id=14) AND ((`Advertisement`.`expiry_date` >=
'2014-11-18') OR (`Advertisement`.`expiry_date` IS NULL)) GROUP BY
`Advertisement`.`id` ORDER BY `Advertisement`.`id` desc LIMIT 10
```

Original Cakephp Code..

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
        'Advertisement.status'=>1,
        'Advertisement.category_id'=>$cat_id,
        'OR'=>array(
               'Advertisement.expiry_date >='=>date('Y-m-d'),
               'Advertisement.expiry_date'=>null
                   )
       );
```

Help me..
Thanks You..

Answer (score 0):

this should be a painless switch.  This first query calls the category ids that you're wanting within your main query.

$cat_id is the same variable you're using in the original query.

```
$ids = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $cat_id, 
        'parent_id' => $cat_id
        )
    )
);
```

The important thing to note here, this query will output your typical nested array..

```
array(
    array(),
    array(),
    array()
);
```

The classicExtract function will sift through the mess for you and give you a single array with a list of 'id' which is exactly what you want for your query. EX:

```
array(14, 15, 16, 18, 19);
```

Finally, your main query.

```
$this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
    'Advertisement.status'=>1, 
    'Advertisement.category_id'=> Set::classicExtract($ids, '{n}.Category.id'),
    'OR'=>array(
        'Advertisement.expiry_date >=' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'Advertisement.expiry_date'=>null
    )
);
```

**Conclusion**
All together your new conditions will look just like this:

```
$ids = $this->Category->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $cat_id, 
        'parent_id' => $cat_id
        )
    )
);

$this->paginate['conditions'] = array(
    'Advertisement.status'=>1, 
    'Advertisement.category_id'=> Set::classicExtract($ids, '{n}.Category.id'),
    'OR'=>array(
        'Advertisement.expiry_date >=' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'Advertisement.expiry_date'=>null
    )
);
```